# Nonnegative upper derivative implies continuous function nondecreasing. Why is this not obvious?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I know I'm underthinking this.  Can someone tell me why I'm wrong?

I'm looking at Royden's Chatper 5, Proposition 2.  It states:

If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and one of its derivatives $(D^{+})$ is everywhere nonnegative on $(a,b)$ then $f$ is nondecreasing on $[a,b]$.

Doesn't this follow from the definition of each derivative?  For example, the numerator of $D_{-}$ is $f(x)-f(x-h)$.  So $D_{-}$ is only nonnegative when $f(x)\geq f(x-h)$.  How does increasing not follow from this fact?

Here $D_{-}$ is defined as $\liminf_{h\to0^{+}}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$

Comment: Nonnegative doesn't mean positive.

Comment: Thanks!  I edited what I have up there.  All we need to show is $f$ nondecreasing, so the difference between nonnegative/positive I don't think attacks the crux of my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

*Deja vu* and not obvious.  The way to find out whether something is obvious is to write up a formal proof.  If you find that it still feels obvious but you can't write it up because it is "too obvious."  Well ... not so obvious after all.

Also don't cheat and work with the *lower* right (or left) Dini derivative.  That makes the problem a lot easier, but still  not "obvious" to my taste.

The theorem itself is due to Dini, not surprising considering the name we use for these four "derivatives."

> ```
>   U. Dini, Fondamenti per la teoretica delle funzione di variabli reali, Pisa 1878.
> ```

There is a full account in S. Saks, *Theory of the Integral* (1937) p.~204 including a more general but similar version due to Zygmund.